# ng-repeat and custom filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array that has inside 3 elements.

Example:

```
arrayMain {
                {test1: 1, test2: 2, subArray: Array(5)}
              }
```

so 2 elements are just numbers, but the third is an array.

What I need a custom filter for is this:

I have a ng-repeat in the view, that creates a row for each element in `arrayMain` so in my case it creates 3 rows, but I need it to only take in consideration `subArray`, so if `subArray` is there, create 1 row, if it's not, don't create anything.

How can I write a custom filter for that?

Thank you

Comment: define a "row", do you want it to look like a table? I think it's enough to have `ng-show="row.subArray.length"` to show or hide your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with NgIf on the NgRepeat tag

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arrayMain" ng-if="item.subArray.length > 0"></div>
```